How change status "onbackorder" (preorder) instead "outofstock" for one variation?
Perhaps someone know, how make status "onbackorder" (when users can do preorder) instead "outofstock" for one variation of one variable product by SKU, attribute_name and value of this attribute.
For example there is a variable product:
sku = 'TEST-001';
attribute_name = 'pa_size';
value = '35';

There are other attributes, but I need to identify variation by this attribute 'pa_size'. I'm trying to make it using some coding in functions.php file of my theme:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'enable_backorders_for_variation', 10, 3 );
function enable_backorders_for_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Get the SKU, attribute name, and value you want to target
    $sku_to_find = 'TEST-001';
    $attribute_name = 'pa_size';
    $target_value = '35';

    // Check if the variation matches the SKU
    if ( $variation->get_sku() === $sku_to_find ) {
        // Get the variation attributes
        $attributes = $variation->get_attributes();

        // Check if the attribute exists and matches the target value
        if ( isset( $attributes[$attribute_name] ) && $attributes[$attribute_name] === $target_value ) {
            // Enable backorders
            $data['backorders'] = 'yes';
        }
    }
    return $data;
}


Just enable for the related variation "allow backorders" option in its settings, this doesn't need any code for that.

@LoicTheAztec so eazy, yes:) but I have a plugin that updates statuses every hour, and it’s even more difficult to redo it. I just want to create new function and execute by Cron it every 10 minutes, for example

So you gonna have one function to update it (wrong) and another to correct it ? Why not just exclude it from the plugin ?
